# i18next key string from backend Argument of type '[`description.${string}`]' is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: typescript, i18next

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNu9e.png)

```
    const keyFunction = (): string => 'part1';
    const key = keyFunction();
    console.log(key);
    console.log('with key:', i18next.t(`description.${key}` as const)); // error
    console.log('no key', i18next.t('description.part1'));
```

TS2345: Argument of type '[`description.${string}`]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[.......]'

how to fix this?

in dificul way keyFunction return from backend data whith translations keys and must put in i18next.t(`description.${item.part}`)

created i18next.d.ts as examples
then create interface whith translation

Comment: opened i18next master example and put the same code and get error

Comment: in v23 not work i18next.t<any>(description.${item.part})
in v22 it works i18next.t(description.${item.part})
problem in lib
resolved